# discord.py Bot not responding before reaction add

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've coded a discord bot that adds a role to a user who reacted to a message. The bot also replies to the message 'Hallo Bot'. But when I turn off the bot and turn it on again, the bot won't reply to the message before I reacted to the other message.

```
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        mitglied = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name="Mitglied")
        if str(payload.emoji) == "":
            await payload.member.add_roles(mitglied)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.startswith("Hallo Bot"):
            await message.channel.send("Hallo " + str(message.author.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
        mitglied = discord.utils.get(user.member.guild.roles, name="Mitglied")
        user_id = reaction.user.author.id
        user = client.get_user(user_id)
        if reaction == "":
            await user.add_roles(mitglied)
```

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
       if message.content.startswith("Hallo Bot"):
          await message.channel.send(f"Hallo <@{message.author.id}>")
```

Your code is being executed in one single event, and that should not be the case as message and reaction are 2 different events. I've separated them, now whenever you type "Hallo Bot" the bot should reply to you before you having to react to the message.

Comment: Instead of putting a piece of code and a vague “try this” explain what and why doesn’t work in his code, what have you improved, what have you done to fix it.

Comment: I don't get a reference to 'client' at the decorator.

Comment: Edited for context. @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: `client` is the name of your client instance. The one you used to create `discord.Client()` and the one used in `.run()`. If you called your variable of the instance something else (for example `bot`) change `@client.event` in `@bot.event` .

Comment: I know  what `client` is and named it like this, too. But the reference at the decorators are unresolved. But just at the decorators, it works everywhere else where I used it.

Comment: I changed everything that the code works again. But it still doesn't response before I add the reaction.